# PHP 5.4 json_decode generates malformed json

Tags: php, json

I do have an odd problem regarding PHP Array to JSON serialization:

I got an array of many layers and to a certain size, it works just fine. But at some point, the closing curly bracket is missing from the returned JSON object.
Here are the returned headers.

```
Date: Fri, 29 Dec 2017 12:42:39 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding, userid, dealerid
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 8503
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
```

The API is built using the SLIM 3 Framework for simple REST APIs.

Setup on the API:

```php
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
...

public function listFailedOrders(Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
  $arr = [];

  //algorithm to fill array
  //verified that the array has data that is not malformed in any way!

  $responseData = [];
  $responseData['count'] = count($arr);
  $responseData['data'] = $arr;

  $response = $response->withJson($responseData, 200);
  return $response;

}
```

Data Returned:

```js
{
 "count": "41",
 "data": [
  {
           .... JSON DATA ....
  },
  {
           .... More JSON Data ....
  }
 ]
//Missing End curly Bracket
```

I use Insomnia Rest client to inspect this and until this point, my only solution to this problem is to add a closing curly bracket on the receiving end.

TLDR:
I serialize a big (not limit reaching object) to JSON but the trailing curly bracket is trimmed. Where does the problem originate from?

Comment: 1. try to increase `memory_limit`,  2. if will not help, so set: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` will show errors if they exist. 3. try to just echo data with `echo json_encode($rawArrayOrObject); exit(0); `

Comment: I can sort out the Memory Limit issue. The Memory Limit is set to 2GB and the data sent is merely 10KB

Comment: 5 mb is ok, but in case of memory allocation for non serialized object it may be more. Think about ORM and etc kinds of object where You've 2 fields and 10s of methods that operate with that 2 fields

Comment: When echoing the json_encode the curly bracket is actually there. I guess it is an issue with slim!

Comment: Or data to json serialiser works not as expected. But strange that slim has such issues. I've not experienced such stuff with slim in my experience.

Comment: Instead of again assigning to variable $response, just return in the previous line and see the difference. Just a try. :)

Comment: @Akilan nice mentioning, it also should help, due to GC works after the scope and generating new offset in memory also takes resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a preset Content Length Header which cut off the last curly bracket.
This was a bad mistake.